# jQuery disable checkbox with certain class once one is checked

Tags: php, jquery

So I have some php code that is spitting out checkboxes for Avatar. However the person can only select one of the images in their gallery to be their avatar. However When they check one of the boxes I want to be able to disable all the others. I can't seem to figure this out. Tried many different things so I thought I would ask with specific code.

```
echo 'Avatar: <input type="checkbox" name="membersview[]" class="memberavatar" value="'.$galleryid.'" /><br />';
```

So what I want is if a user checks any checkbox that has a class of members avatar. I would like to disable the other checkboxes that have the class of membersavatar.

Some Sample HTML output so you can see how it is being renedered by the browser

```
<form action="/members/members_gallery.php" method="post" id="memberdetail">
<div style="width:150px; height:200px; float:left; margin:0; padding:0; border:0;">
    <a href="../site/images/gallery/users/ninja@theringersclan.com/1390202957-20130816_193346.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img src="../site/images/gallery/users/ninja@theringersclan.com/1390202957-20130816_193346.jpg" style="width:150px; height:150px; margin:0; border:0; padding:0;">
    </a> 
    <br>Is Public: <input type="checkbox" name="galleryid[]" value="5">
    <br>Members: <input type="checkbox" name="membersview[]" value="5" checked="checked">
    <br>Avatar: <input type="checkbox" name="membersview[]" class="memberavatar" value="5">
    <br>Delete: <input type="checkbox" name="deletepic[]" value="5">
    <br>
</div>
<div style="width:150px; height:200px; float:left; margin:0; padding:0; border:0;">
    <a href="../site/images/gallery/users/ninja@theringersclan.com/1390203939-240_screenshots_2014-01-19_00001.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img src="../site/images/gallery/users/ninja@theringersclan.com/1390203939-240_screenshots_2014-01-19_00001.jpg" style="width:150px; height:150px; margin:0; border:0; padding:0;">
    </a>
    <br>Is Public: <input type="checkbox" name="galleryid[]" value="7" checked="checked">
    <br>Members: <input type="checkbox" name="membersview[]" value="7" checked="checked">
    <br>Avatar: <input type="checkbox" name="membersview[]" class="memberavatar" value="7">
    <br>Delete: <input type="checkbox" name="deletepic[]" value="7"><br></div><div class="cl">
</div>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="galleryupdatepics" value="Update Pics" style="float:left">
```

Comment: What you're asking is more like the operation of "Radio button" so i would suggest you to consider use the more natural controls for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this -

```
$function(){
    $('.memberavatar').click(function(){
          $('.memberavatar').not(this).each(function(){
              $(this).prop("disabled", true);
          });
    });
});
```

JSFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/wzNdL/

---

**UPDATE**
To mimic a radiogroup, but only after the 1st is 'unchecked', try something like this -

```
$(function(){
    $('.memberavatar').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
              $('.memberavatar').not(this).each(function(){
                  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
              });
        }
        else {
              $('.memberavatar').prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wzNdL/4/

Comment: This is the closest. However if I uncheck it is not toggling the rest as enabled. can you help write a quick if statement to help toggle?

Comment: I have updated to check if `is(':checked')`, if not to removed the 'disabled' prop.

Comment: Thank you sir. This worked perfetly. -- AND THANK YOU TO ALL for all your suggestions and taking the time out of your day to help others :)

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
$('.memberavatar').click(function(event) {
    $('.memberavatar').prop('disabled', true);
    $(event.target).prop('checked',true);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5K8L6/

Of course in this case it would make more sense to use radio buttons instead of a checkbox

Comment: I agree a hundred percent. However I don't have a choice my boss loves the look of a checkbox. So therefore .. Monkey do what boss says ha ha

Comment: Are you sure you want all other checkboxes disabled and not unchecked? To add to this answer, you'll want to add logic to re enable all others when the checked one is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

This will work pretty nicely.

**Code:**

```
$("input:checkbox.memberavatar").click(function () {
    $(':checkbox').not($(this)).attr('checked', false);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqPmw/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.memberavatar').click(function(){
    $('.memberavatar').not(this).each(function(){
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
    });

});
```

But as you've been told you'd better off using radio buttons. The above function simply makes checkboxes of certain class to behalf like radio buttons.